# Error while Starting Server Webshere 7

Tags: java, websphere

I am not able to start a server in WAS .it is throwing below error

com.ibm.ws.exception.WsException: FFDCHelper - Unable to create directory  /IBM/websphere/was7.0/profiles/PT_STS_HK_APP1/logs/ffdc

while creating a directory manually i am getting:

$ mkdir ffdc
mkdir: 0653-358 Cannot create ffdc.
ffdc: There is an input or output error.

Comment: The ffdc directory is only used for ffdc error logs. Is that really the reason why the server is not starting up? Are there any other errors in the logs? It could be that the reeal reason why the server is not starting up is what was about to be logged in ffdc.

Answer (score 1):

As you are getting the error when using mkdir, it is unlikely that it is anything but a problem on your server. A hard disk may be dying.

You don't tell us which OS you are using, but Linux/unix would give a more specific error if permissions were the problem.

Comment: i am using aix...and it is allowing me to create directory other than ffdc

Comment: Try googling on **aix "input or output error"**. The consensus seems to p[oint towards a hardware or disk formatting problem.